# Publishing page is firing ItemUpdated event twice the first time it is edited

Tags: event-receivers

I have a custom SharePoint solution that creates an enterprise wiki site based on a word document of a particular format.

I have an ItemUpdated event receiver attached to the Pages library for some custom processing. The first time any page is edited ("Save and Close") my event receiver runs twice.

Thinking my code was the culprit, I added a return; statement after my logging statement which is the very first statement of the function, and the problem continues.

I checked using SharePoint Manager to confirm that my event receiver is not registered twice. I do notice that there is an ItemUpdating event receiver handled by "Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyItemEventReceiver" and an ItemUpdated event receiver handled by "Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PagesListCPVEventReceiver". Could one of these be the culprit?